# How to prevent transition to run on page load after height is set with javascript in Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, css-transitions

I have a div on a page with liquid height that i want to animate with CSS transitions to collapse/expand.

I set the default height of the div using JS, so if i change the height with CSS, it can easily revert back to the original state. Works fine, the issue is that the height animation will run on page load in Safari. (works fine in Chrome) Any idea how to fix this?

CSS:

```
div {
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1) 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.hide {
  height:10px !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$div = $('div');
$div.height($div.height()); 

$div.click(function(){
    $div.toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/69taau5m/1/

Comment: I don't have Safari so can't check. Does setting the `transition` with JS after setting the height fix the issue? As an aside, is a delay of 0s really needed? :D

Comment: Tried that, not working. Delay is not needed, but i change that with a class later, so thats why its there:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a little hacky but you could always apply the `transition` to your `div` on click as well.

Did this pretty quick but it works. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69taau5m/2/). Could always add some logic to only apply css on the first click.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I guess its a Safari bug, so i'll accept this answer.